# Got stuck when using hdfs for logdirs of MonitoredTrainingSession of distributed tensorflow

Tags: hadoop, tensorflow, hdfs, distributed

I am using between-graph replica with hdfs, but my program got stuck when the parameter of MonitoredTrainingSession-logdirs is set to hdfs://default/mypath4train_logs. The code is like:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                           is_chief=(worker_index==0),
                                           checkpoint_dir="hdfs://default/mypath4train_logs/train_logs",
                                           config=sess_config) as sess:
```

I have read the documentation on tensorflow guide [how to run TensorFlow on hadoop](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/hadoop), and done whatever it says, in which, most importantly, the paths to libjvm.so and libhdfs.so have been appended to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

However, the chief worker's log stopped at:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
2017-10-09 23:34:55,575 Create CheckpointSaverHook.
```

I debugged it, it seems that the program got stuck on tensorflow::FileSystem::RecursivelyCreateDir, yet without any error. Here's exactly how I debugged it:

```
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function _ZNSsC1ERKSs@plt,
which has no line number information.
0x00007fc181431260 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function _ZNSsC2ERKSs,
which has no line number information.
0x00007fc1a1aeddcd in 
tensorflow::HadoopFileSystem::Connect(tensorflow::StringPiece, hdfs_internal**) ()
from /search/odin/tensorflow/py34tf1.3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function _ZN10tensorflow16HadoopFileSystem7ConnectENS_11StringPieceEPP13hdfs_internal,
which has no line number information.
0x00007fc1a1aef752 in tensorflow::HadoopFileSystem::FileExists(std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
from /search/odin/tensorflow/py34tf1.3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function _ZN10tensorflow16HadoopFileSystem10FileExistsERKSs,
which has no line number information.
0x00007fc1a1d31ffa in 
tensorflow::FileSystem::RecursivelyCreateDir(std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
from /search/odin/tensorflow/py34tf1.3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function _ZN10tensorflow10FileSystem20RecursivelyCreateDirERKSs,
which has no line number information.
```

Notice that the last command of gdb has never returned.

I have also found these tow similar questions yet are either unsolved or unhelpful for my problem:

[Distributed Tensorflow 1.0 Supervisor stuck if logdir is in HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354494/distributed-tensorflow-1-0-supervisor-stuck-if-logdir-is-in-hdfs?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[How to use hdfs directory path in tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession API for writing logs and checkpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843494/how-to-use-hdfs-directory-path-in-tf-train-monitoredtrainingsession-api-for-writ#)

Comment: I solved this question by building a new hadoop cluster of version 2.7.6, the older hadoop I was using is 0.19.0, maybe that's the reason.